# Plone configuration

Tags: plone, zpt

Plone is showing the special chars from my mother language (Brazilian Portuguese) in its pages. However, when I use a spt page I created it shows escape sequences, e.g.:

```
Educa\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o
```

instead of

```
Educação
```

(by the way, it means Education). I'm creating a python function to replace the escape sequences with the utf chars, but I have a feeling that I'm slaving away without need.

Comment: You're going to need to tell us how you're inserting the string if we're going to be able to help. Meanwhile, http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/internationalization-i18n-and-localization-l10n may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you interpolating catalog search results? Those are, by necessity (the catalog cannot handle unicode) UTF-8 encoded.

Just use the `.decode` method on strings to turn them into unicode again:

```py
value = value.decode('utf8')
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way should be to use safe_unicode function https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/utils.py#L458

```
from Products.CMFPlone.utils import safe_unicode
value = safe_unicode(value)
```